# Django - trailing slash resets page title

Tags: python, django, url, trailing-slash

I apologise for the blatant ignorance of this question but I've been charged with fixing something in Django that I have **NO** experience with!

We're getting an issue with URLs and duplicated content.

If we visit "www.hello.com/services/" then we get our full page rendered, absolutely fine.

If we visit "www.hello.com/services" then we get the same content but with a default  that seems to be set in a line:

```
class PageTitleNode(template.Node):?
 ?
    def render(self, context):?
        try:?
            meta_info = MetaInfo.objects.get(url=context['request'].path)?
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:?
            return u'This is our default page title'?
        return u"%s - hello.com" % meta_info.title
```

The main problem with this is that Google is indexing two almost identical pages and it's bad SEO according to our client's overpaid *online strategy partner*.

I know it's vague but if anyone can help then much rejoicing will be had.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your consultant is correct. One URL = one resource. Having two urls on one resource is quite dirty anyway. This is why Django features automatic redirect from non trailing slash to urls with trailing slashes. Under [certain conditions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash).

I'm pretty sure **your url definition regexp for /services/ lacks the trailing slash**. Anyway, you should use **trailing slashes only**:

1. **Ensure [APPEND_SLASH](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash) is set to True**: `from django.conf import settings; print settings.APPEND_SLASH`
2. **Ensure that all your url regexps have the trailing slash**, e.g. `url(r'foo' ...)` is **bad**, and `url(r'foo/' ...`) passes **barely** because of possible conflicts and `url(r'foo/$' ...`) is **better**
3. **Ensure all MetaInfo objects have url with trailing slash**, e.g. `MetaInfo.objects.exclude(url__endswith='/')` should return MetaInfo without trailing slash in url

Comment: Many thanks for your advice on this - it's not something I'm able to implement myself but I've passed it to someone with a little more confidence than me!

Comment: I'm glad I could help - you should forward the above advice to the person you passed it too just in case it could help her/him. Please [close the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).